# kill executable from XNA c#

Tags: c#, xna

I was wondering how to kill an executable file from xna. i call the file from xna but when i try to close it,  it just wont. I am using the Process.Kill() method, I was wondering if the if statements had something to do with this. I am trying to call the .exe when i press 2 and close it when i press 3.

here is the code i have so far.

...
private Process hello;
...
...

```
      if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D2) || gamePadState.Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
      {
       hello = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\VC\Downloads\On-ScreenKeyboardPortable\On-ScreenKeyboardPortable.exe");


      }

    if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D1) || gamePadState.Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        hello.Kill();
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? If not, set a breakpoint at the `Kill` line, as I have a feeling it's not being called.

Comment: i inserted the break point and the game window closes, but not the keyboard.

Comment: What do you mean by 'The game window closes, but not the keyboard.'? When you press the button, it closes the game and leaves open the keyboard?

Comment: Yes, the keyboard is a different executable file, it remains open, and the game icon on the file doesnt close completely it remains in a "not responding status"

Comment: But does the breakpoint get activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("processName");
process.Kill();
```